# Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

```
        Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init> + 9(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216047@20.12.16 (040308-0):9)
               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cv.a + 23(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216047@20.12.16 (040308-0):23)
               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.m.run + 14(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216047@20.12.16 (040308-0):14)
               at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Google Maps Crashes i tried launch the screen with the following:

> - Map Fragment
> - Add Marker
> - Draw Polly line
> - I have used Dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

Device Motorola Z Play(Android 8.0)
I could not figure out the issue as it keeps on crashing in some devices. How can I solve this?

[image: Device Details]

[image: Android 5.1 & Android 8.0]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The issue got resolved by Uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the issue was because of Play-services SDK it worked, Thanks @halfer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is problem with Google Maps SDK, not with your app. Recommended solution is to clean app data from Settings. Or app reinstall.

You can track Google fixing this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

Comment: thanks, i did find out this later, thanks, expecting the issue to be resolved as soon as possible

Comment: The issue got resolved by Uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the issue was because of Play-services SDK it worked, Thanks @Kubik

Comment: @Mukesh But we can not make all of our users to uninstall and reinstall our app :/

Comment: yes but it should be fixed by now, i got the reply from google